# Explode: Allowed memory size of

Tags: php, yii2

Есть код:

```
public function actionImagedelete($id)
{
    $explode = explode("_", $id);
    if (isset($explode[1])) {
        $id = $explode;
    }
    if (is_array($id)) {
        foreach ($id as $ido) {
            $this->actionImagedelete($ido);
        }
    }
```

он работает.
однако так:

```
$explode = explode("_", $id);
$id = $explode;
```

или так:

```
$id = explode("_", $id);
```

он не работает и выдает ошибку:

> Allowed memory size of.

Почему так?

Comment: вам для решения задачи точно рекурсия нужна? и что вы передаете как параметр в метод этот? конкретный пример, на котором падает.

Comment: @teran, передает строку вида "123" или "123_124". после чего разбивает в массив и дальше уже проводит действия. падает с любой строкой.

Comment: @teran, а рекурсия сильно снижает производительность? если да, то, наверное, я мог бы обойтись без нее.

Comment: вообще использование рекурсий не рекомендуется (только в крайних случаях)

Comment: @Дмитрий использовать рекурсию надо просто к месту и с понимаем что это такое. Нельзя говорить, что использовать рекурсию не рекомендуется. Есть задачи для которых этот метод подходит идеально. Некоторые задачи можно решать разными методами, как р рекурсивными так и линейными. Основные минусы рекурсивного метода - разрастание стэка вызовов и съедание на  этом памяти, и потенциальное его переполение, в т.ч. в случае бесконечности. Однако, нерекурсивные решения так же будут требовать использование дополнительной памяти в т.ч. для хранения вспомогательных структур.

Comment: Поэтому однозначно сказать, какое решение предпочесть можно только для конкретной задачи на конкретном объеме данных, а не просто "не рекомендуется"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите по шагам, как работает текущий и модифицированный код.  На вход вы получаете строку `123`. Исходный код с `if`

1. `$explode` принимает значение [ 0 => "123"]
2. ветка `if()`  не выполняется (элемента с индексом 1 нет), `id` остается строкой `"123"`
3. проверка `is_array()` не выполняется (`id` строка), завершение работы

Далее вы убираете начало кода заменяя его на `$id = explode("_", $id);` получаем

1. `$id` принимает значение `[0 => "123"]`  и становится массивом
2. проверка `is_array` выполняется
3. для каждого (единственного) элемента в цикле запускается рекурсивный вызов `$this->actionImagedelete($ido);` в данном случае, аргументом будет опять же строка `123`.

Поскольку это рекурсия, то мы попадаем опять на шаг 1, и аргумент вызова у нас точно такой же как и первый раз. Отсюда следует простой вывод - мы получаем бесконечную рекурсию, которая съедает все ресурсы и приводит к нехватке памяти.

Не совсем ясно, что вы вообще хотите сделать с помощью данного кода. Вряд ли здесь требуется рекурсия вообще, но для решения задачи, нужно понять какая  вообще цель всего этого. По сути в коде действий никаких нет, только рекурсивный вызов.

Comment: да, тут моя глупость взяла верх, как и всегда. переделал без рекурсии.